# Using fileset in ant apply with a mapper

Tags: ant

This feels like it should be a common issue, but I haven't been able to find the duplicate answer yet.

I have a bunch of object files, and if any of them have changed they all need to be passed to the linker exec. I have an `apply` task as follows:

```xml
<target name="linker">
    <apply executable="link.exe" parallel="true">
        <arg value="-o" />
        <targetfile />
        <srcfile/>
        <fileset dir="obj" includes="*.o"/>
        <globmapper from="*.o" to="myapp.exe"  />
    </apply>
</target>
```

The problem is that only the object files that have changed are passed to the linker, and I need to pass all object files (basically the output of the fileset before the mapper has been applied). The linker works fine if I set the `force` attribute on the `apply` task, but I only want it to rebuild if an object file has been updated.

I'm aware that I can use the [Uptodate task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html), but I was hoping I could do it with just the [apply task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) by specifying an additional `fileset` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't the `<fileset>` task, but `<mapper>`. Ant, like most build systems, tries to save time by not processing files that have not changed. The *mapper* is mapping the source (files with the `*.o` suffix), to the target (the `myapp.exe` file).  It's doing exactly what you want.

What you probably want to do is use the `<arg/>` sub-entities to specify the output file name:

```
<apply executable="link.exe">
    <arg value="/out"/>
    <arg value="myapp.exe"/>
    <fileset dir="obj">
       <include name="**/*.o"/>
    </fileset>
</apply>
```

You could use `<uptodate>` to see if any of your `*.o` files were newer than your `myapp.exe` file, but if you use a mapper, you're limiting the `*.o` files to only those newer than `myapp.exe`.

```
<uptodate property="needs.linking"
     targetfile="myapp.exe">
    <srcfiles dir="obj">
        <include name="**/*.o"/>
    </srcfiles>
</uptodate>

<target name="linker"
    if="needs.linking">
    <apply executable="link.exe">
      ...
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first snippet will cause `link.exe` to be run on every build (as I believe you alluded to when discussing `uptodate`). As implied in my question I've already implemented a solution with an `uptodate` task, but I'd prefer to just use `apply` if possible. As `apply` supports both `uptodate` checks (via the `mapper`) as well as `filesets`, I would have thought it could have been done without an explicit `uptodate` task?